How to revert this action?
I had made a face and tried to bevel one of the edges.
I must have clicked something that is similar to control+B but isn't because afterwards the computer was stuck loading and then I got this weird geometry:

Control+Z won't revert my geometry.
What have I done and how do I revert it?
Edit:
If it helps to figure out the problem, I noticed that when moving my point of view the only parts of the original mesh that are visible are always within this long face that suddenly appeared.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

You probably clicked Alt + B by accident, which clips your viewport to only show a selected part of the scene. Simply click Alt + B again to reverse the viewport clipping.
You can also see that you have your viewport clipped by the "(clipped)" at the top left of your screenshot.
